# How to rewind last swipe like Tinder

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on an iOS app (using Objective-C).

I am using [MDCSwipeToChoose](https://github.com/modocache/MDCSwipeToChoose) API to swipe a view (like & dislike).

I want to add one more button in the App (rewind [last swipe](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/social-media/11445619/Tinder-Plus-lets-premium-users-rewind-to-their-last-swipe.html) like [tinder](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/tinder/id547702041?mt=8)).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want NSUndoManager. See the following links for examples.

[Implementing NSUndoManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439803/implementing-nsundomanager)

http://nshipster.com/nsundomanager/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: What about a link to another question in stack overflow?

Comment: If an answer on another post completely satisfies the requirements of this question, then it's probably a duplicate. I would strongly recommend **not** answering a question on SO with _just_ links to sites - but I would post them as a comment to a post or question, if you think they would help the OP or future readers. Further reading on link-only answers here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers (and I didn't downvote... fyi)

Comment: Good link! I think this particular question is tricky because implementing my suggested solution is already covered several times in SO, but I didn't find "undoing a swipe" anywhere, so the question itself is not a duplicate. Plus there might be other solutions worth suggesting (perhaps this mystery downvoter is typing their suggestion as we speak).

Answer (score 1):

You can create separate manager that will handle current card number. On revert button action, you can remove previous card and animate appearance of the new one. 
You can look how we implement this manager here:
https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda